# Cannot flush cache error when uploading data with scriptella to Teradata using FASTLOAD

Tags: sql, jdbc, etl, teradata, scriptella

I tried to upload data in a CSV file to an empty table I created. But got the following error:

```
May 21, 2014 10:18:18 AM <INFO> Execution Progress.Initializing properties: 1%
May 21, 2014 10:18:18 AM <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=in_file, CsvConnection, Dialect{CSV 1.0}, properties {}: 3%
May 21, 2014 10:18:19 AM <INFO> Execution Progress.Initialized connection id=db, JdbcConnection{com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_FastLoadManager_Connection}, Dialect{Teradata Teradata Database 13.10.07.24}, properties {statement.batchSize=100000}: 5%
May 21, 2014 10:18:19 AM <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/query[1] prepared: 10%
May 21, 2014 10:18:19 AM <INFO> Registered JMX mbean: scriptella:type=etl,url="file:/xxx/fastload.xml"
May 21, 2014 10:18:44 AM <INFO> Execution Progress./etl/query[1] executed: 95%
May 21, 2014 10:18:44 AM <INFO> Execution Progress.Complete
May 21, 2014 10:18:55 AM <WARNING> Unable to rollback transaction for connection CsvConnection: Transactions are not supported by CsvConnection
May 21, 2014 10:18:55 AM <SEVERE> Script /xxx/fastload.xml execution failed.
Unable to commit transaction - cannot flush cache
JDBC provider exception: Unable to commit transaction - cannot flush cache
Error codes: [HY000, 1154]
Driver exception: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.17] [Error 1154] [SQLState HY000] A failure occurred while inserting the batch of rows destined for database table "mydatabase"."myemptytable". Details of the failure can be found in the exception chain that is accessible with getNextException.
```

This is my fastload.xml file:

```
<!DOCTYPE etl SYSTEM "http://scriptella.javaforge.com/dtd/etl.dtd">
<etl>
<description>Scriptella  script</description>
<properties>
    <include href="$config"/> <!--Load from external properties file-->
</properties>
<connection id="in_file" driver="csv" url="$inputfile">
</connection>
<connection id="db" driver="$driver" url="$url" user="$user" password="$password" classpath="lib/terajdbc4.jar">
statement.batchSize=100000
</connection>

<query connection-id="in_file">
<!-- Empty query means select all columns -->
<script connection-id="db">
INSERT INTO  mydatabase.myemptytable VALUES (?1,?2,?3);
</script>
</query>

</etl>
```

This is my connection URL:

```
url=jdbc:teradata://mypath/TMODE=ANSI,CHARSET=UTF8,TYPE=FASTLOAD
```

Uploading without FASTLOAD works for the same file. 
I tried to google the error message but did not find anything. Anyone know what's the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you would be better off using a `PreparedStatement` for `FastLoad`. Please have a look [here](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFAF) and [here](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20205JD.java.txt)

Comment: I have read the doc/code you posted. And I have tried the code, it worked. The problem here is that I need to use scriptella, not Java JDBC. Did not find a right way to do this in scriptella.

Comment: I'm sorry then, have never used `Scriptella` with `Teradata`.